# Chrome extension with parse.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parse-platform, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension. What I am trying to ask is about how to save my current login state after I close the extension. For example, my extension are allow me to login, but after I login, when I close the extension, it will automatically load to the first page where is the login page.

Here are the manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version"  : 2,
"name"              : "My Book",
"version"           : "1",
"description"       : "Securing your bookmark",
"background" : {
    "scripts"       :["scripts/parse-latest.js"],
    "persistent"    : true

},
"icons"         :{
    "16"            : "images/16icon.png",
    "48"            : "images/48icon.png",
    "128"           : "images/128icon.png"

    },
"browser_action" : {
    "default_icon"  : "images/20icon.png",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
},
"permissions"       : ["tabs","bookmarks","storage","contextMenus"]
```

}

Here are the popup.html

```
<form>
        <div>
            <label for="userField">Username: </label>
            <input type="username" id="login-user" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="passField">Password : </label>
            <input type="password" id="login-password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="login-submit" class="login-submit" value="Login" title="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here are the popup.js

```
Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, {
        success: function(user){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Login success");
            /*window.location.href="popout.html";*/
            /*chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popout.html'});*/
            $('#logoutBtn').show(); 
            $('#loginForm').hide();
            //alert('1');


        }, error: function(user, error){
            console.log("Login error: " +error.message);
            //alert("Wrong id/password");
            //document.write("error");


        }
    });
```

Comment: Popup window is recreated each time it's shown. You'll need to save the login state somehow (cookies or token). Check the parse.com API documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you for your suggestion, but I not really understand about how to save the state. Do you have any example to show me?